# Godot Specified cast is not valid when adding child to node

Tags: c#, nodes, instance, godot, multiple-instances

Trying to make a boids simulation in Godot, and I think I have the rules set up right for movement however when trying to make a C# script for the node that will hold all the instances of each boid scene, it throws this error in the debugger `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid` when adding the child.
The scene builds and starts fine but crashes and that shows in the debugger. The boid scene is an Area2D node with all the math for movement and steering in it:
[image: Boid Scene]

(The root Area2D node has a script with class Boid that inherits from Area2D as well)

Here is the code for the System node:

```cs
using Godot;
using System;


public class BSystem : Node2D
{
    [Export] public int num = 10;
    private PackedScene Boid;
    public override void _Ready()
    {
        Boid = ResourceLoader.Load<PackedScene>("res://Boid.tscn");
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            Area2D boid = Boid.Instance() as Area2D;
            AddChild(boid);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: As I see it, Boid is of type `PackedScene` and the instance would also return that type. How do you know it is an `Area2D`?

Comment: @AMunim The [`Instance`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_packedscene.html#class-packedscene-method-instance). method of `PackedScene` returns `Node`. And [`Area2D`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_area2d.html) inherits from `Node`. Presuming the `Node` is actually an `Area2D` - which is what OP claims - the cast would be correct. Edit: How would OP know? It is the type of the root node of the scene `"res://Boid.tscn"`.

Comment: You can't go from parent to child :P

Comment: How about testing your hypothesis, Exotik850? You could print the result of `Boid.Instance()` and see what you actually got.